# Teleric-MVC tag misspelled?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, spelling

I just noticed this question: [Mvc(Razor Engine) Telerik Tabstrip validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000101/mvcrazor-engine-telerik-tabstrip-validation).

In its tags, it has `teleric-mvc`. Should this not be `telerik-mvc`? This might cause some confusion in searching for this, if so.

Comment: Can't you just edit it?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Probably. But I didn't want to touch it in case it was really legit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There already was a [telerik-mvc](/questions/tagged/telerik-mvc) tag with the correct spelling and nearly 700 questions.  I just created a synonym to link the two so any new questions with the misspelled tag will be retagged automatically.